# Python reading and translating binary field of MS Access

Tags: ms-access, python-2.7, binary

I have a MS Access(.mdb) file. In this db there is a field in **Object type** (checked with LibreOffice Base). I used [pyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) to read that field. Here is the connection string:

```
db = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=c:/test.mdb;Uid=;Pwd=;')
```

After connecting i took first row (**Object type**) to examine. Here is:

```
(bytearray(b'\x9bp\xb8\xbe\xb4\xc0\xd0\x11\x83y\x08\x00\t\xb9\x96\xcc\x01\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00A\x00l\x00g\x00o\x00r\x00i\x00t\x00h\x00m\x00i\x00c\x00 \x00C\x00o\x00l\x00o\x00r\x00 \x00R\x00a\x00m\x00p\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x92\xc4\xe9~#\xd1\xd0\x11\x83\x83\x08\x00\t\xb9\x96\xcc\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Y@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x19=\x00\x00\x92\xc4\xe9~#\xd1\xd0\x11\x83\x83\x08\x00\t\xb9\x96\xcc\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00^\xe7w\x846\xaaK@\x86wV\xf1_\xd4-@\x83\x02\xae\x12\x9c\x18Q\xc0\x00\x00'), )
```

Other rows are str or int type but Object row is different. I have no idea about type of this data. I searched and tested some examples but i am stucked. How can i take meaningful info from that.

Answer (score 0):

This is OLE-object field. As usually there is linked or embedded COM object serialized into byte array. May be this link could be useful http://www.lebans.com/oletodisk.htm